# Firebase dynamic link, social share issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, socialshare

I have recently finished developing my app, and I have stuck with an issue, which I don't understand. So here is the problem:

I am creating firebase dynamic LONG link in my app, for referring users, which looks like:

[image: manualy creating the long dynamic link]

field WEBSITE_MAIN is "http://www.thebeonapp.com"

Than I shorten the link programmatically by URL shortener and share the link for example in messenger. The link looks like

[[image: link in messenger]]

1. Clicking the red highlighted link (the short one, works perfect)
2. By clicking the green highlighted part (the social title, description or image), than the long link is somehow malformed and opened in browser (website can not be found).

Is there a workaround how to correct/avoid this issue ?

Of course my app is available in BETA version on the google play, if you want to test this issue in real. Here is the link:

[BeonApp - The new Open World](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wisdominvest.beonapp)

Thanks for all the answers in advance!

ADITIONAL INFO:
This issue only appears in messenger. (Whatsapp works correctly)

Comment: It's suppose to be `afl` and not `dfl`. `afl` stands for `androidFallbackLink` which is the link to open when the app isn't installed. Specify this to do something other than install your app from the Play Store when the app isn't installed, such as open the mobile web version of the content, or display a promotional page for your app.